# Pyhton Databricks 2 sources and columns not named the same

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 2 sources and the columns are meant to be the same however one column namen "orderdate" from Source 1 is named in Camel case(OrderDate) and the same column in source 2 is names in lowercase(orderdate).

The schema I need to apply has the column named "orderdate". Source 2("orderdate") column populates without any issues and Source 1 ("OrderDate") populates NULLS.

I tested by changing the column name in the schema to camel case and Source 1 ("OrderDate") populates correctly and Source 2("orderdate") populates NULLS.

How can I have this work for both columns?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, 
IntegerType, DateType

    # define the schema for the data sources
    schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("orderdate", DateType(), True)
])

# read in the two data sources with the defined schema
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
"true").schema(schema).load("path/to/source1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
"true").schema(schema).load("path/to/source2.csv")

# union the two data sources
df = df1.union(df2)
```

Comment: Please provide the code your are running, so we can understand better.

Comment: Did you try using alias for one of the columns?

Comment: @DipanjanMallick am I able to give a column an alias as at the ingestions stage? I am trying to create dataframes. If possible could you please share how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to get the data from source 2 with the camelcase name,  rename the column to lowercase and then union the two dataframes:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, 
IntegerType, DateType

    # define the schema for the data sources
    schema1 = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("orderdate", DateType(), True)
])

    # define the schema for the data sources
    schema2 = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OrderDate", DateType(), True)
])

# read in the two data sources with the defined schema
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
"true").schema(schema1).load("path/to/source1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
"true").schema(schema2).load("path/to/source2.csv")

df2_renamed = df2.withColumnRenamed("OrderDate","orderdate")

# union the two data sources
df = df1.union(df2_renamed)
```